# Cannot run R script which is in the local directory

Tags: r, r-package, library-path

I installed an R library (https://github.com/behavioral-ds/evently) using `devtools::install_github()`

This library (`evently`) is installed in `Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library`. On the other hand, I have the same directory (evently) in my local folder: `Docs/proj` (because I cloned the github URL in this local folder).

I have to run the following lines (to build retweet cascades):

```
library(evently)
filepath <- system.file('extdata', 'tweets_anonymized.jsonl', package = 'evently')
cascades <- parse_raw_tweets_to_cascades(filepath, progress = F)
```

The `parse_raw_tweets_to_cascades` function is in the `tweet.R` file. When I edit the `tweet.R` file and run the above lines of code, **it runs the original "evently" library, and not the one I am editing (in Docs/proj)**

I tried the following:

```
library("evently",lib.loc="~/Docs/proj/evently")
```

but I get the error: "there is no package called ‘evently’". How can I run the R file from the local directory?

### Update/Answer

The answer provided by Konrad Rudolph worked for me. I just used `devtools::load_all()` instead of library(`packagename`).

Comment: You need to use `devtools::load_all()` instead of `library` to load the package.

Comment: ...and that's because *cloning* a Github repo does not *install* a package.

Comment: You asked this question [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75844640). See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054) Q&A on Meta about unanswered questions.

Comment: @MikaelJagan: thanks for mentioning the Meta page. I will update my question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: @Limey: I installed the package using `devtools::install_github` (as suggested in the library github page). Also, according to the [discussions in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101232/whats-the-difference-between-using-devtoolsinstall-github-and-cloning-a-git), `devtools::install_github` installs a package directly from git repository. The reason I used git clone was because I wanted to edit the codes.